# IDE для Python

Tags: python, ide, python-faq

Среды разработки и текстовые редакторы для разработки на Python. Их плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 31):

## [IDE](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments):

- [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm) - Community (бесплатная) или Professional (платная) версии. См. [сравнение возможностей](https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=pycharm&product=pycharm-ce).
- [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/features/python/)
- [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) + [плагин](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/61688/python)
- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org) + [Pydev](http://pydev.org/)
- [PyScripter](https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter)
- [Wing](http://www.wingware.com)
- [Eric Python IDE](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/eric-download.html)

## [Редакторы](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors):

- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) + [расширение ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) - по удобству работы приближенно к уровню IDE.
- [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com)
- [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html) - плюс в том, что поставляется вместе с Python, возможно это единственный плюс. Лучше использовать другие редакторы.
- [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)
- [Gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit)
- [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs) + [elpy](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html)
- [Vim](http://www.vim.org)
- [Nano](http://www.nano-editor.org)
- [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org)

## [REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) (интерактивные оболочки):

- [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin)
- [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)
- [ptpython](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/ptpython)
- [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org)

Comment: Лично я использую Netbeans, правда ядро интерпретатора поставил отдельно (Jython это всё таки не то).

Comment: я тут решил еще раз на сайтик зайти Wing'a. Позиционируют себя очень серьезно.вобще было бы интересно узнать кто,что думает о Wing для приложений и как там дела с веб-фреймворками обстоят.

Comment: Ссылки в vim + bpython перепутаны :)

Comment: @neoascetic, исправил.

Comment: Список хороший, но кое с чем не соглашусь. Gedit и nano -- ни разу не IDE даже с плагинами. ipython -- это REPL, даже не редактор как вышеупомянутые. Emacs тоже просто мощный редактор, надо бы указать плагины, которые его "умудряют".

Comment: Ох, какой же старый вопрос оказывается, как же он всплыл... За некропостинг прошу прощения.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если есть `Intellij Idea`, то можно накатить на нее какой-нибудь плагин и будет тот же самый `PyCharm`. Это так?

Comment: @MichaelPak Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 15):

PyCharm весьма удобен. Умеет дружить с Django.

Из минусов: платен, довольно тяжеловесен, хочет много ресурсов, долго индексирует проект при старте.

Comment: Есть бесплатная версия. [Сравнение возможностей](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2010 начал официально поддерживать Python ([Pytools](http://pytools.codeplex.com/))

Answer (score 6):

Использую [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/). Лучше не встречал, хотя и пользовался немногими.

Answer (score 5):

Geany - отличный редактор с кучей все возможных настроек. Весьма удобен для написания кода на Python.
Aptana - большей редактор с возможностью подключения всевозможных плагинов.

Comment: Geany хорош до тех пор, пока не начинает в строках код подсвечивать :/

Answer (score 4):

Использую Emacs. Из самого важного для разработки на Python -- наличие весьма неплохого python-mode, [jedi](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/) для автокомплита и [flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) для проверки синтаксиса на лету (не только для Python, но и для него тоже). Есть еще [rope](https://github.com/python-rope/ropemacs) -- неплохой режим для рефакторинга (и автокомплита тоже), но лично я его не использую.

Большой плюс Emacs -- единая среда "для всего". Есть достаточно неплохие режимы почти для любого языка (а для некоторых только Emacs и есть), огромное количество других вкусностей (один [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) чего стоит), ну а степень гибкости настройки всяким IDE и не снилась.

При этом Emacs далеко не идеален, у него есть разные врожденные и исторические проблемы (шутка ли, сколько ему лет), кривая его изучения довольно крутая, так что запастись терпением придется, но освоив этот редактор, настроив под себя, серьезно поработав в нем, пересесть на что-нибудь еще почти нереально (я честно пару раз пытался смотреть по сторонам).

Comment: Поддержу. Автор ответа указывает очень полезные плагины, без которых от emacs особых чудес ждать не стоит.

Comment: [elpy](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) собирает несколько пакетов вместе (включая упомянутые `jedi`, `rope`): упрощает настройку, совместное использование, но может быть не слишком стабильным.

Answer (score 3):

только начал изучать питон, остановился на PyScripter - есть портабл версия! причем всегда свежая, все вместе и интерпритатор и IDE сразу, почти ничего не надо настраивать, очень удобно.

Answer (score 3):

присоединяюсь к Geany, по сравнению с остальными очень легковесен, есть и под линуксы и под виндовсы...

- множество гибких настроек
- поддержка достаточно большого числа
     языков программирования
- в юниксах есть встроенный терминал

изначально работал с Eclipse, но меня раздражала медлительность и то что нужно было кучу всего до устанавливать, в том числе и плагин для работы с html файлами

ЗЫ

Если вы работаете только на винде 32-х разрядов, то лучшим решением будет все таки PyScripter

Answer (score 3):

У меня в openSUSE менеджер пакетов в разделе IDE помимо всевозможных Geany, KDevelop, QtCreator, Anjuta предлагает Eric - Python IDE. Помимо Python, она еще и под Ruby заточена. Сама среда написана на Python + Qt + QScintilla. Последнее является как плюсом (кроссплатформенна), так и минусом (чтобы запустить, нужно поставить и настроить вышеописанное). Разумеется, свободно-распространяемая, локализована.

Выглядит симпатично, хотя я не особо пишу на Python.

Возможности (перевод списка с главной страницы проекта):

- Неограниченное количество редакторов
- Настраиваемое расположение элементов среды
- Настраиваемая подсветка синтаксиса
- Возможности автодополнения
- Подсказки с вариантами вызова
- Свертывание кода
- Поиск парной скобки
- Подсветка ошибок
- Продвинутые возможности поиска, включая поиск-замену во всем проекте
- Встроенные обозреватель классов
- Встроенный интерфейс к CVS
- Подключаемые модули поддержки Subversion и Mercurial
- Встроенные возможности коммуникации (чат, совместный редактор) - только в eric5
- Встроенная система документирования кода
- Встроенный отладчик Python с поддержкой многопоточных приложений
- Встроенный полнофункциональный отладчик Ruby
- Встроенный профайлер
- Встроенные средства проверки кода (синтакс, ошибки, стиль) - только в eric5
- Встроенные средства управления задачами (список todo)
- Продвинутые возможности управления проектом
- Встроенные оболочки к Python и Ruby
- Диаграммы приложения
- Запуск внешний приложений из IDE
- Встроенная поддержка юнит-тестов
- Встроенная поддержка CORBA на основе omniORB
- Подключаемый модуль средств рефакторинга
- Подключаемый модуль, обеспечивающий интерфейс к cx_freeze
- Подключаемый модуль, обеспечивающий интерфейс к PyLint
- Масса встроенных мастеров
- Локализация, в том числе поддержка русского языка
- Средства предпросмотра форм Qt и локализации приложений
- Встроенный обозреватель web
- Встроенный интерфейс к спелл-чекеру

[Сайт проекта](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/)

Comment: мне Eric - Python IDE не понравилась, помнится у нее были какие то бока с надстройками... вроде при нажатии табуляции должно вставится 4 пробела, они как то неверно вставлялись и воспринимались не как 4 пробела. Было что то еще, но я уже и не помню, я от нее быстро избавился.

Answer (score 2):

Советую Komodo Edit: поддерживает автодополнение кода, макросы и тоже OpenSource.