# С какой IDE лучше начать работь с Python на Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ide

Привет. Читаю книгу A Byte of Python. Как лучше начать работать без меньшей путаницы? Gedit или PyCharm? Полагаю все же в дальнейшем PyCharm все равно станет основной? Если сразу в ней работать, то не создаст это лишней путанницы для новичка?

Comment: Пользуйтесь тем, что вам удобно. Программный код - это всего лишь текст. Можете работать в любом текстовом редакторе. Даже в Vim.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к предыдущему оратору. Учиться лучше всего с простым текстовым редактором и командной строкой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [IDE для Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464/ide-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-python)

Comment: что вы под путаницей имеете ввиду? что вы хотите получить от IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оффтопну слегка. Когда читал "Укус Питона", использовал смартфон на Андроиде 4.2 + бесплатное приложение из маркета QPython 3. Для этой книжки - отличный вариант. Особенно для тех, кто долго едет в метро.
А в Убунту использовал gedit.

Comment: Во. Спасибо! Как книжка? Помогла стартануть? Я совсем без опыта)

Comment: Очень. Отличная основа. Далее советую почитать книжку Марка Лутца  "Программирование на Питон". Кажется четвертое издание.

Comment: Та что программируем или изучаем? А уже применяете Python на практике? С какой целью он понадобился?

Comment: А расскажите, как вы на 33й странице сделали чтобы файл helloworld.py запускался из любой директории по команде helloworld?

Comment: Сейчас пишу систему управления задачами сотрудников нашего отдела. Написал интерфейс на основе Тк и ттк, хранилище на базе sqlite3. Сейчас буду придумывать модуль удаленного оповешения сотрудников о несвоевременно исполненных задачах. Пока около 200 строк, без учета sqlite запросов. Питон начал изучать около 3,5 мес. назад. До этого знал только основы sas+sql.  А вот насчет второго вопроса подсказать не могу, потому что учился на андроиде и вин7, линукс поставить некуда.

Comment: Спасибо на добром слове!) Python клёвый ;-)