# Лучшая Python IDE для начинающего, на Ваш взгляд и личный опыт

Tags: python, windows, ide

Всем доброго времени суток. Я дизайнер по профессии, но вот решил начать изучать программирование и первым языком выбрал Python (этот выбор основан на личных приоритетах) и тут столкнулся с задачей, а какую же IDE выбрать для обучения?
Всякие там Notepad++ и ему подобные просьба не предлагать. Так как хочу приучить себя к одному IDE и больше с него не слезать.
Желательно предлагайте бесплатные версии или условно-бесплатные, но чтобы они небыли настолько урезаны, что смогли бы ограничить меня в обучение и заставлять купить полноценную версию.

Пока я точно не определился что именно я буду делать на пайтоне, это может быть как разработка ПО, так и Веб разработка. Поэтому прошу предлагайте действительно хороший продукт, которым я смогу пользоваться и не парится, что там не поддержки этого или другого.

Спасибо большое за то что прочитали и простите за мою придирчивость :)

Comment: если npp не нравится, посмотрите на [sublime text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), на плагинах можно построить что-то более/менее похожее на ide, если чего-то будет не хватать - всегда можно написать свой плагин на том же питоне )

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464/ide-для-python?rq=1 а тут плохие списки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm или Visual Studio.
В первом более удобно писать код, во втором более удобный отладчик.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А они обе бесплатные?

Comment: Есть как бесплатные версии, так и платные, для учёбы бесплатной версии хватит вполне.

Comment: Однозначно PyCharm!

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд лучшая IDE это Visual Studio Community. Она является бесплатным и очень удобным инструментом разработки.

1. Скачайте и установите [VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)
2. Скачайте и установите расширение   [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо. Возьму на заметку. А что по поводу ограничений в этой версии, они есть или это полно-функциональная версия программы?
И есть ли там поддержка Веб разработки на пайтоне? Джанго и т.п.

Comment: @SneByorn, для индивидуальных разработчиков ограничений вообще нету. Джанго, отладчик, intellisense, unit тесты и т.д. все поддерживается.