# Как вставить уже готовый код в IDLE?

Tags: python, idle

Только начал учиться программировать. Python 3.6. shell. 
Если вставить уже готовый код (например с блокнота) в IDLE, то только первая строчка кода начнется с ">>>", а все строчки ниже будут начинаться без ">>>" и программа выдаст ошибку.
Но если копировать код построчно, после каждой строки нажимая Enter, то каждая новая строчка будет начинаться с ">>>" и код будет выполняться. Копировать код строка за строкой неудобно, а как копировать код целиком и чтобы он работал? Заранее спасибо, в гугле не нашел. Где-то туплю.
[image: Скоприровал сразу с блокнота]

Comment: Сохранить в файл, в idle файл - открыть.

Comment: связанный вопрос [IDE для Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В IDLE идём в меню File и выбираем пункт New File (или просто нажимаем Ctrl+N).
2. В новом открывшемся окне вставляем текст, скопированный из блокнота (или откуда Вы там копируете...)
3. Сохраняем файл с удобным именем в удобном месте. Не забываем про отступы - Python к этому ооочень чувствителен.
4. После того, как файл сохранили, можно его запускать: F5 или Run ->
   Run Module